# key value pair object for qml properties

Tags: qt, qml

I would like to store the angular position of my switch to then set the rotation accordingly according to the switch status, so I would like to store javascript key value objects like this (not working pseudocode, to express what I want):

```
Item {
    id:parentWheelSwitch
    property int status:0
    Item {
        id: posInt
        property {1:30}
        property {2:15}
        property {0:0}
        property {3:-15}
        property {4:-30}
        property {5:-45}
        property {6:-75}
    }
}
```

or for example,

```
Item {
    id:parentWheelSwitch
    property int status:0
    Item {
        id: posInt
        property whatever {
            1: 30,
            2: 15,
            0: 0,
            3: -15,
            4: -30,
            5: -45,
            6: -75
        }
    }
}
```

That way then I would be able to handle the switch status and the angular position at once.
Is there any neat way to have this key-value with int properties params stored in qml? Seems very useful to be handled afterwards with js code.

Comment: use `property var whatever  {`

Comment: omg, i tried const and let, but var is kind of obselete in js, so I was not aware. I'll check that out, thanks a lot

Comment: Note that the var here is not the js var. It is a qml type meaning it can hold everything, not an access specifier or variable declaration or whatever it's called for var/let/const in js.